# How to opt out of a @Where filter for an individual JPQL query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have an entity mapped with a [`@Where`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-where) annotation like:

```
@Where(clause = "is_active = 1")
```

That works fine, but now I want to write a query that doesn't use the annotated filter condition in the `where` clause.

The only way I can think of is to fall back to a native query.

Is there a way to disable a filter for a single specific query?

I'm using a `JpaRepository` `@Query` annotated interface method to declare my query  like:

```
 @Query(name = "UnmergeStudent", value = "select .... student_1.lui = :lui")
 List<UnmergeStudentSummary> findMergedStudentSummaryByLui(@Param("lui") String lui);
```

I looked at the members of the `@Query` annotation but can't see anything obvious.  Is there a way to avoid filters if I fall back to writing the actual query code in a normal method?

Hibernate version is 5.2.10.Final

Comment: It is stranger. I did the same you, however I use JPQL with Left Join with two entitys, one of them has Where filter and the result obey the query JPQL response and no Where filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable `@Where` but you could use `@Filter` instead.

The difference between `@Where` and `@Filter` is that `@Filter` can be parameterized and `@Filter` has a name and must be turned on using that name:

```
entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class)
    .enableFilter("your_filter");
```

Read more about this in the offical documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filtering